# Dynamically set background color of ion-item in an ion-list

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic5

I'm attempting to set the background color of an <ion-item> component in an Angular application but I can't seem to get it working with code.

If I view the page and manually change the css of the element to have `--background: red` in the browser then it works as seen below.

[image]

However, if I try to change it via code then the CSS doesn't show up at all in the browser on the element and of course the color isn't changed.

```
<ion-list inset *ngIf="socketService.connected$ | async">
  <ion-item
    *ngFor="let user of users$ | async"
    button
    (click)="selectUser(user)"
    [ngStyle]="{ '--background': user.color }"
  >
    <ion-label color="primary">{{user.name}}</ion-label>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

I've also moved the expression bound to `[ngStyle]` to a method that returns an object just so I can make sure that proper css is being returned and it is. `user.color` is a hex color in the form `#XXXXXX`

Answer (score 1):

Using `[style.--background]="user.color"` on the ion-item worked. I guess Angular was removing the style since it started with `--`

Answer (score 0):

## IONIC VUE

You can use `:style` directive:

```
<ion-item :style="{'--background': 'yellow'}">...<ion-item>
```